# split and get value after string in consolidated value using c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get the value from the `List<string>` which contains different format as below.

Formats:

```
var fieldValue =  { 
      "00 1234567 89 EXT 098", 
      "001 234 56 789 EX 0987",  
      "0 0123456789 EXTEN 09",
      "00123456789 EXTENSION0987",
      "00123456789E098987" 
}
```

Among all these values, I want to get the value **('098', '0987', '09', '0987', '098987')** after string such as **'EXT', 'EX', 'EXTEN', 'EXTENSION', 'E'**

The string may be differ in each value, so that I confused to apply condition to get the values after that.

Also I am unable to split this using `<space>` since it may contain in some values.

Please advice me to get the required values. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replacement on `^.*?(?=\d+$)` and replace with empty string:

```
string input = "00123456789E098987";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "^.*?(?=\\d+$)", "");
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This prints:

```
00123456789E098987
098987
```

Note: In the case of an input which does not end in at least one digit, the above logic would just return that original input.  I.e. `123ABC` remains as that.

Comment: solution given is working fine. much appreciated, thank you

Comment: @Ramanan Next time you ask a question, try to include whatever code you have tried.  Doing that would have avoided some of the downvotes.